# Using CSS Sticky property to bump up an item when scrolling to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a "to the top" button that sits fixed in the lower right-hand side of my page. It has a margin of 15px on the bottom, but my footer is 120px and I want the button to line up with the center of the footer when you reach the bottom of the page (in other words, the bottom margin becomes 35px). I've been trying to use the position:sticky property to achieve this, but as it is right now, the button 1) is in the bottom left for some reason, and 2) acts lik. Here's the THML and the CSS I'm using:

```css
.up-to-the-top {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 55px !important;
    height: 55px;
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
    margin-right: 15px !important;
    border-radius: 50px !important;
    background-color: #230000;
    padding-top: 11px !important;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
.up-to-the-top:hover {
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="up-to-the-top-container">
    <a href="#site-header" class="up-to-the-top">
      <svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2160 1280.02"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:white;}</style></defs><polygon class="cls-1" points="200 1280.02 1079.99 400 1960.01 1279.99 2160 1079.98 1079.98 0 0 1080.02 200 1280.02"></polygon></svg>
    </a>
  </div>
```

[image: Reference image of footer (arrow shows where the button should be)]

Comment: any screen shots?

Comment: Could you make a snippet which we can run and which shows the problem - your given code just shows the uparrow without the footer etc context.

Comment: _“(in other words, the bottom margin becomes 35px)”_ - so in other other words, the button that was sitting still in one fixed position all the time, would now suddenly _move_ its position? That doesn’t sound very user-friendly to me.

Comment: @RifkanRazak I added in a screenshot. Obviously you can't see this, but the arrow acts like a static element even with position:sticky.

Comment: @AHaworth I'm not sure how to add a snippet, but would the screenshot do?

Comment: @CBroe The button would only move 20px up, not even half its height. It's really just an aesthetic thing; as you can see in the screenshot, the arrow is below the center of the footer vertically. I've tried just increasing the bottom margin when it's fixed, but then it's too high up on the page and it's distracting. Therefore, I want to use the sticky feature.

Comment: _“The button would only move 20px up, not even half its height.”_ - that could still be enough to suddenly move it out from under my mouse cursor, if I had it hovered before during scrolling already (because I already intended to jump back once I was finished reading the content on this site.) _“It's really just an aesthetic thing”_ - a lot of usability mess-ups are born from those :-)

Comment: @CBroe That's a fair point. My logic here is that since it's a button that takes you to the top of the page, and its position would only move when you scroll all the way to the bottom, that kind of mistake wouldn't happen. But if that does end up being a problem, it would still be nice to know how to use the sticky feature even if it doesn't end up being useful for this button.

Comment: @AHaworth I take that back, I figured out how to add a snippet. I had to add a few lines of CSS just to make it look like it does in the screenshot, but the problem stays the same. If you switch position:sticky to position:fixed, you'll see that the button appears in the correct place, but right now it appears in the upper right corner for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.up-to-the-top-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50px !important;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    height: 55px;
}
```

Change the position sticky to position fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as per your need, Hope this helps you

```css
 .up-to-the-top {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #230000;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 4px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 30px;
      right: 30px;
      transition: background-color .3s, 
        opacity .5s, visibility .5s;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    .up-to-the-top:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="up-to-the-top">
      <svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  style="width: 32px;padding-top: 12px;" viewBox="0 0 2160 1280.02">
        <defs>
          <style>.cls-1{fill:white;}</style>
        </defs>
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="200 1280.02 1079.99 400 1960.01 1279.99 2160 1079.98 1079.98 0 0 1080.02 200 1280.02">
        </polygon>
      </svg>
</div>
```